# c# best way to hide connectionstring?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I've been looking around for a while now on how to hide the connectionstring so it's impossible for the users to see my database information. How do I do this? If possible can you maybe give me an example?
Thank you!

Comment: you can put it in an encrypted section of your `.config` file

Comment: Also, do not use SQL Server authentication.  Use Windows authentication instead (no passwords in .config, encrypted or otherwise).

Comment: If your client app connects directly to the database, your users already have (or can easily get) the connection string. If that's not acceptable, you need to add a middle tier (or write a web app).